Python access to Authorize.Net API Not Connecting
I have the following python code:
      from authorizenet import apicontractsv1
      from authorizenet.apicontrollers import *
      from authorizenet.apicontractsv1 import merchantAuthenticationType, getMerchantDetailsRequest


      merchantAuth = apicontractsv1.merchantAuthenticationType()
      merchantAuth.name = "LOGINID"
      merchantAuth.transactionKey = "APIKEY"
      request = getMerchantDetailsRequest()
      request.merchantAuthentication = merchantAuth
      controller = getMerchantDetailsController(request)
      controller.execute()
      response = controller.getresponse()
      if response is not None and response.messages.resultCode == "Ok":
          print("API Login ID and Transaction Key are correct.")
          print(f"Merchant Name: {response.merchantName}")
      else:
          print("Invalid API Login ID or Transaction Key.")
          if response is not None:
              print(f"Error Code: {response.messages.message[0].code}")
              print(f"Error Message: {response.messages.message[0].text}")
      return False

I have verified my Login ID and API Key and they are correct.  When I log the requests, I get the following error:
ERROR:authorizenet.sdk:Error retrieving http response from: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api for request: <xml.dom.minidom.Document object at 0x7f9c8b240160>
ERROR:authorizenet.sdk:Exception: <class 'AttributeError'>, ("module 'requests' has no attribute 'post'",)
DEBUG:authorizenet.sdk:Did not receive http response

I've googled arounf for some time but cannot find an answer on how to fix this.  Any help is appreciated.
Used curl to confirm my API Key and Login ID:
{"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}

